# How to read Hexadecimal format data from device?

Tags: java, sockets, gps

Can any one explain how to read data from the device using socket programming. The device is sending Hexa format so am not able to read that data please help me how to do that.

```
StringBuffer instr = null;
instr = new StringBuffer();
buf = new byte[4096];
int br = socket.getInputStream().read(buf);
for(int i =0;i<br;i++){
            instr.append((char) buf[i]);

            }
data = instr.toString();
```

Am using above code so please help me.

Comment: You mean you get binary data (i.e. bytes) and don't know how to interpret that data? Do you know anything about the format of that data?

Comment: yes am getting binary data . the device is sending hex format but we are not able to read that format its like unreadable format.

Comment: Explain "Hexa" format.  Give an example of the input that is "unreadable".

Comment: It seems likely that you are actually able to read the input, but are not able to understand the format of the input.

Comment: 000F33353238343830323539353132303900000134D331C0BD002BE6B0400E92F51001F4001E0C0000000602010002000309000C0A001518000001C70000000000. And am getting some chains language. sorry am not able to paste that format/

Comment: Read the documentation for the device in question, it should explain the format of the output (your input).

Comment: I already go through the document but there is no solution for this

Comment: You should not put the bytes into a string but rather operate on the binary data directly. What you need to do in order to get the format you need should be described in the documentation for the device in question, as @DwB already stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code snippet

```
public String convertHexToString(String hex){

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

          //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
          for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

              //grab the hex in pairs
              String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
              //convert hex to decimal
              int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
              //convert the decimal to character
              sb.append((char)decimal);

              temp.append(decimal);
          }
          System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

          return sb.toString();
      }
```